node-opcua | Generating around 100K variables in node-opcUA server takes so much time. How to optimize?
I'm using node-opcua server to test my application and i want to create 100K points in that address space having random values. I've just used a simple loop to create variables in batches but it takes too much time to even generate a small batch of 5K points but it's taking almost 10-20 minutes to generate that batch. Any one how to create 100K points in bulk in node-opcua server?
const opcua = require("node-opcua");

let allPoints = [];
let totalPoints = 100000;
let batchSize = 5000; 
let currentBatch = 0; 


function construct_address_space(server) {
    const addressSpace = server.engine.addressSpace;
    const namespace = addressSpace.getOwnNamespace();
    
   // Function to create a batch of points
   function createBatch() {
        for (let i = currentBatch * batchSize + 1; i <= (currentBatch + 1) * batchSize; i++) {
            const vessel = namespace.addObject({
                browseName: `Vessel_${i}`,
                organizedBy: addressSpace.rootFolder.objects
            });

            let variable = {
                nodeId: `ns=1;s=Variable${i}`,
                browseName: `Pressure_${i}`,
                dataType: "Double",
                value: {
                    get: function () {
                        return new opcua.Variant({dataType: opcua.DataType.Double, value: Math.random()});
                    }
                },
                componentOf: vessel
            }

            const vesselPressure = namespace.addVariable(variable);
            allPoints.push(vesselPressure);
        }

        currentBatch++;

        if (currentBatch * batchSize < totalPoints) {
            console.log(`Created ${currentBatch * batchSize} points`);
            setTimeout(createBatch, 10000); // Wait 1 second before creating the next batch
        }
    }

    createBatch();

    // let t = 0;
    // setInterval(function () {
    //     for(let i = 0; i < allPoints.length; i++) { 
    //         let value = Math.random();
    //         let point = allPoints[i];
    //         point.setValueFromSource({ dataType: "Double", value: value });
    //     }
    // }, 60000);
}

(async () => {
    try {
        const server = new opcua.OPCUAServer({
            port: 26543,
            resourcePath: "/UA/MyLittleServer", 
            nodeset_filename: [opcua.nodesets.standard]
        });

        await server.initialize();
        console.log("certificateFile = ", server.certificateFile);
        console.log("privateKeyFile  = ", server.privateKeyFile);
        console.log("rejected folder = ", server.serverCertificateManager.rejectedFolder);
        console.log("trusted  folder = ", server.serverCertificateManager.trustedFolder);

        construct_address_space(server);

        await server.start();
        console.log("Server is now listening ... ( press CTRL+C to stop)");
        console.log("port ", server.endpoints[0].port);
        const endpointUrl = server.endpoints[0].endpointDescriptions()[0].endpointUrl;
        console.log(" the primary server endpoint url is ", endpointUrl);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error = ", err);
    }
})();

